# Byte array to xml with UTF8 and base64 encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding, decoding

```
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", DataType="base64Binary")]
    public byte[] get(...)
```

I am trying to get a xml(utf-8) from this webservice. I have tried multiple things to try and get the xml out of the byte array like:

```
stream
encoding
decoder
converter
```

[Extra info]
When decoding the byte array with Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
I get a string with strange signs and symbols but also with some text
Starting with: %PDF-1.4

[SOLUTION]
Writing the byte array to a pdf file makes it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the web service provides a byte stream that is simply base64-encoded data represented as integers instead of chars. I believe that the base64 chars are a subset of ASCII, so you need to convert the byte array to ASCII (i.e. base64 represented as chars), then convert these chars from base64:

```
var base64AsAscii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFromWebService);
var decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bytesAsAscii);
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it, but i got following error.
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Comment: This is the response after the get string.

%PDF-1.4
%????
5 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 319/Length 96/Height 238/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x???1

Comment: @Kenny - My code includes 2 calls to GetString: which one? Anyway it looks like the base64 data encodes PDF content, not simple text.

Comment: The first get string gives that response.

Comment: @Kenny - I'm trying to understand this weird name _base64Binary_. You say the XML is UTF8 so might be worthwhile trying UTF8 for _both_ calls to GetString?

Comment: On the other hand the response you posted (%PDF...) clearly isn't base64. You could write the bytes directly to a file, name it with a _.pdf_ extension and try opening it.

Comment: @Kenny - why is the data not base64 when the schema attribute specifies _base64Binary_? I think it would help if you update your question with the code that gets the bytes from the server.

Comment: Can we message in private? I'll send you the webservice url and you can see the method??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43510/discussion-between-groverboy-and-kenny)

Comment: @Kenny - chat room is active.

Comment: Hey, i found it, it's just a pdf file. So if i write it to pdf, i can see it. Now i am trying to put it in a string without writing it to a file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kenny - Great. Does that mean I answered your question?  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: No, it does not work. I tried the convert methods. Is there anyway to know which decoding i need to do? I just need to get my data from the byte array